# ACPI PCC probe failed when "Try Ubuntu 15.04"

Tags: system-installation, 14.10, 15.04, acpi

I installed **Ubuntu 15.04** from pendrive on my notebook Asus and it worked fine for about 7 months. One day the system couldn't start anymore (because of some update maybe?) so I decided to reinstall it. Unfortunately without success. The problem was the same.

Here is what I see when I'm trying to install **Ubuntu 15.04**:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8blDDO00gR5WjJvUTZaNE1EWDQ/view

Things I did to solve this problem:

1. I tried to install **Ubuntu 14.10** and it worked as you can see here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8blDDO00gR5LWJjVXRRcDNvMU0/view (maybe installation of **Ubuntu 15.04** is bad?)
2. I downloaded fresh installation of **Ubuntu 15.04** and tried again but it didn't help so I got another notebook (also Asus) and checked there. As I expected there was no problem so pendrive and installation of **Ubuntu 15.04** were good. (maybe there is some problem with the notebook?)
3. I sent it to the service but they didn't find any problem with hardware.
4. The last thing I tried was install **Ubuntu 14.10** and upgrade it to **15.04** via terminal. Still nothing.

I found many information about reinstall grub2 or NVIDIA drivers, but how can I do it if I just select "try ubuntu" and I'm not able to go to /etc/, sudo, systemctl because of unable to start system? I formatted HDD so it's clean but it didn't help also.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: I'd be interested to know if there was ever a solution found for this.  I'm having this same problem.